# Betweenness centrality measurement ignoring inverse paths?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I'm implementing the **Betweenness Centrality** algorithm proposed by **Brandes** (first algorithm on [this](http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/publications/b-vspbc-08.pdf) paper - also below), and I'm running into a very weird issue: **it seems to be ignoring some paths** (i.e. for vertexes `v-w`, it may count the path `v-e-w`, but not the inverted path `w-e-v`). I'm not sure how to prove or debug this issue, but I'm pretty certain that's what happening. The precise issue that I can see in the debugger is that two nodes that should have the same BC value are off by roughly three units. I'm using the `double` type to store the values.

Am I missing something about this algorithm? The graph I'm examining is *unweighted* and *undirected* btw.

Also, on a totally unrelated note: the value being computed on each step is the following:
[image]

Shouldn't the value be between 0 and 1?

Algorithm:

[image]

Comment: I think it's a bug in the pseudocode. I've translated it to c# and i'm getting BC values greater than 1

Comment: Be realistic man, there is no bug in this psuedocode. Brendas's algorithm is used by everyone including many famous libraries. Try to find the bug in your code and see which part you haven't understood.

Comment: Do you have any links to implementations? The second line starting from the end is giving me values > 1 all the time

Comment: Let me give you an example. On graph `1--2--3` i would expect BC of 1/3 for node `2`, but this algorithm gives me `2`

Comment: I deleted my first comment. The value can be larger than 1. In the example that you mentioned, node 2 has BC 2 and the output is correct.

Comment: I suggest asking one question per question.  You seem to have two separate questions (you even call the second one "totally unrelated", which might be an exaggeration, but it still seems different enough that it should be posted as a separate question).

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm that you have mentioned here is definitely correct. You can refer to the correctness proof in the paper.

This algorithm is implemented in many libraries and ready to be used including [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html), [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/betweenness_centrality.html), [GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Algorithms/Betweenness-Centrality_1.0/), and [MATLAB (3rd party I guess)](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10922-matlabbgl/content/matlab_bgl/betweenness_centrality.m) and many others. Also, many other people (including myself) and companies have employed the same algorithm.

If you are getting unexpected results, please revise your implementation.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It turned out to be an error in my implementation. Thanks!